# Does Go support nontype generic parameter as in C++?

Tags: go, generics

By using C++, I can write something like:

```
template<int siz> 
void myFunc(){

}
// and call
myFunc<13>()
```

I tried type generic parameters and Go supports it, but does Go support this non-type generic parameter?

Comment: Why are you asking? What are you trying to do? Go isn't C++ but whatever you want is probably possible using different features than what you expect. Generics are *not* the same as templates to begin with.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is this proposal: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44253

Answer (score 1):

> but does Go support this non-type generic parameter?

No.